# JSP with Spring MVC - ${} variables not showing

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC for this app, its a very simple one just for test purposes, just save and view data from the db. This is the first page with a simple link to another page using ${context.root} to set the base url. Heres the code from the page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Mah oeeee!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Alunos!</h1>

    <a href="${context.root}/SGE/aluno/cadastro">Novo aluno</a>
</body>
```

The thing is, instead of showing for ex.: `http://localhost:8080/SGE/aluno/cadastro` on the link, it shows `http://localhost:8080/SGE/${context.root}/SGE/aluno/cadastro`. Same thing happens on the view page, that shows the data from the database:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>CONSULTA</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Nome</td>
            <td>${aluno.nome}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>CPF</td>
            <td>${aluno.cpf}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>E-Mail</td>
            <td>${aluno.email}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Instead of showing the value of the variables, ex.:

```
Nome:     Joao
CPF:      98765482312
E-mail:   joao@joao.com
```

it just shows like this:

```
Nome    ${aluno.nome}
CPF         ${aluno.cpf}
E-Mail  ${aluno.email}
```

What can be the problem so i get it fixed? Can the problem be some configuration on tomcat?

EDIT: Heres the code, as requested:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView index() {
    return new ModelAndView("aluno/index");
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/consulta/{id}")
public ModelAndView consultar(@PathVariable int id) {
    Aluno aluno = getAlunoService().buscarPorId(id);
    return new ModelAndView("aluno/consulta", "aluno", aluno);
}
```

Comment: try `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`. can you paste the controller code? hard to diagnose the problem as it is now.

Comment: I added the code for both views. The thing is, it doesnt matter, how i send the data, what page it is, what variable it is,  if i use ${} it just treats the variables as text o.O

Comment: @onlido maybe you're missing jstl EL jars?

Comment: Is `aluno` really not null in `consultar()`? Also, does the class `Aluno` have the proper getter methods (like `getNome()`, `getCpf()` and so on)?

Comment: What version of Servlet are you using? Prior to 2.3, the JSP EL is disabled by default.

Comment: Yes, the method works just fine in my computer, both tomcat and glassfish. All models have getters and setters. I think it might be a config problem on my host provider, because it runs just fine here at home.

Comment: how can i check my servlet version?

Comment: I dont know where to look at in web.xml, i see a version 3.0 but i dont know if thats it

Comment: Add `<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>` at the beginning of your jsp.

Comment: Check if your file has JSP extension. EL is hardcoded in JSP and should work always until disabled.

Comment: Ill try things up as soon as i can and come back with an answer

Comment: I think it might have to do with my web host. Ill probably have to change hosts since they dont answer my tickets.

Comment: None of the answers worked, tried all of them...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to provide following directive

```
  <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

If you are using maven,then add following dependency

```
  <dependency> 
       <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
       <artifactId>jstl</artifactId> 
       <version>1.2</version> 
 </dependency>
```

Else add **jstl.jar** in your project

Answer (score 5):

Try to start your web.xml as

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
```

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be missing some directives on your web page..

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

You may not need all of those (depending on what you want), but you certainly need some.

Answer (score 3):

Because I just ran into this and this was the first question I found on stack overflow with my exact issue. I thought I would past the solution that worked for me. Please refer to this page.

https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/modelandviews-model-value-is-not-displayed-in-jsp-via-el/

Basically EL tags are ignored via the JSTL if you are using the old style JSP declaration in the web.xml. You can leave it and add

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

to every page you are using EL tags in or you can update to the new style web.xml declaration where EL tagging is used by default.

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">
//...
</web-app>
```

I hope this helps someone else. Many thanks to the mkyong.com page for having the solution I needed.

Comment: The edit to the solution I provided was to update my web-app tag using Dmitry's answer above because it was newer then the one on mkyong.com. I didn't try his answer due to lack of explanation though it is correct.